# Cat's Tail Not Looping Correctly

Tags: animation

So from the previous posts regarding the same I've learnt how to loop the keyframes. But when I do loop it by selecting all points (A) on the F-graph curve and then (Shift+E) on the graph and choosing the option, it doesn't loop the whole tail.

The first cycle is perfect. The tail has 5 bones and they all move.
But after the first cycle only the first bone moves.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are all the bones selected when you select all the keyframes?

Comment: Yup. What the hell is going on! x__x